# Python always getting same result

Tags: python

The program I am writing below has the follow requirements:

```
# Design a program that prompts the user to enter the names of two primary colors
# to mix.  If the user enters anything other than red, blue or yellow, the
# program should display an error message.  Otherwise the program should display 
# the name of the secondary color that results.
```

This is the code I have written - based upon a Java program I have wrote previously and evidently was way off for Python.:

```
print('You will be mixing two primary colors to get a resulting color.')
print('Primary colors are blue, red and yellow \n')

red = False
blue = False
yellow = False

color1 = bool(input('Enter your first primary color: \n'))
color2 = bool(input('Enter your second primary color: \n'))

if color1 == red and color2 == blue:
        print('That makes purple!')

elif color1 == blue and color2 == red:
        print('That makes purple!')

elif color1 == yellow and color2 == red:
    print('That makes orange!')

elif color1 == red and color2 == yellow:
    print('That makes orange!')

elif color1 == blue and color2 == yellow:
    print('That makes green!')

elif color1 == yellow and color2 == blue:
    print('That makes green!')

else:
    print('You did not enter a primary color!')
```

No matter what color combination I enter, I get the result "That makes purple!"  Where did I go wrong with the logic of this program?  Further, when I do not enter green as the primary color, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "color.py", line 19, in <module>
color1 = bool(input('Enter your first primary color: \n'))
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'green' is not defined
```

instead of the error message "You did not enter a primary color!"

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT:  This is my new code and it works other than the erroring out.

```
print('You will be mixing two primary colors to get a resulting color.')
print('Primary colors are blue, red and yellow \n')

red = 1
blue = 2
yellow = 3

color1 = input('Enter your first primary color: \n')
color2 = input('Enter your second primary color: \n')

if color1 == 1 and color2 == 2:
    print('That makes purple!')

elif color1 == 2 and color2 == 1:
    print('That makes purple!')

elif color1 == 3 and color2 == 1:
print('That makes orange!')

elif color1 == 1 and color2 == 3:
print('That makes orange!')

elif color1 == 2 and color2 == 3:
print('That makes green!')

elif color1 == 3 and color2 == 2:
print('That makes green!')

else:
print('You did not enter a primary color!')
```

Comment: You're in python 3, yes?  What do you expect to be returned by `bool('red')`?  You'll _always_ get `True` because the string is non-empty.

Comment: Yeah, this logic makes no sense. `red`, `blue`, and `yellow` are all set to the same value, `False`, but you expect there to be a difference in your `if` conditions? Try to write pseudocode, then convert that into python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be comparing `color1` and `color2` to strings not booleans:

```
color1 = input('Enter your first primary color: \n')
color2 = input('Enter your second primary color: \n')
if color1 == "red" and color2 == "blue":
    print("That makes purple!")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your trouble exists in these lines:

```
color1 = bool(input('Enter your first primary color: \n'))
color2 = bool(input('Enter your second primary color: \n'))
```

When you do this, any non-empty value entered will result in `True`.  The *only* way you'd be able to get `False` would be to hit `return` at the prompt and submit an empty string.  Your logic in how you want to handle what the user enters is a bit flawed.  You might want:

```
if color1 == 'red'
```

After you drop the superfluous call to `bool`, but that's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
color1 = bool(input('Enter your first primary color: \n'))
```

If we simplify this, we get

```
color1 = bool("red") #color1 becomes True
```

So now your comparisons are evaluating does `False` equal `True` - completely ignoring the colors you have inputted.

Try something like

```
RED = 'red'
BLUE = 'blue'

color1 = input('Enter your first primary color: \n').lower()
color2 = input('Enter your second primary color: \n').lower()

if color1 == RED and color2 == BLUE:
    print('That makes purple!')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some **big** problems with your code. First, you call `bool(input())`. As long as you provide *some* input, `color1` and/or `color2` are set to True.

Therefore, you are calling `if True == False`... Your code does nothing to check the actual names of colors. Instead, I suggest using plain `input()` to take in a `**string**.

Here is your edited code:

```
print('You will be mixing two primary colors to get a resulting color.')
print('Primary colors are blue, red and yellow \n')

color1 = input('Enter your first primary color: \n')
color2 = input('Enter your second primary color: \n')

if color1 == 'red' and color2 == 'blue':
        print('That makes purple!')

elif color1 == 'blue' and color2 == 'red':
        print('That makes purple!')

elif color1 == 'yellow' and color2 == 'red':
    print('That makes orange!')

elif color1 == 'red' and color2 == 'yellow':
    print('That makes orange!')

elif color1 == 'blue' and color2 == 'yellow':
    print('That makes green!')

elif color1 == 'yellow' and color2 == 'blue':
    print('That makes green!')

else:
    print('You did not enter a primary color!')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to lie in these lines

```
red = False
blue = False
yellow = False

color1 = bool(input('Enter your first primary color: \n'))
color2 = bool(input('Enter your second primary color: \n'))
```

when you input a color it is just being set to false, regardless of which color it is. to the computer this is happening(I'll use red and yellow as examples)

```
color1 = bool(red)
```

since you defined red earlier as False:

```
color1 = bool(False)
color1 = False
```

Similarly

```
color2 = bool(yellow)
```

yellow is also defined as False

```
color2 = bool(False)
color2 = False
```

So when we get to your first if statement

```
if color1 == red and color2 == blue:
```

the computer sees

```
if False==False and False == False:
```

which evaluates to True

```
if True and True:
if True:
```

Part of your problem might be arising from your use of input(). To python2.x(which I will assume you are using) input() evaluates whatever is entered. For example:

```
input("Enter Something")
>>>3
input("Enter Something Else")
>>>3.1
```

would return the integer value 3 and the float value 3.1 respectively. The computer looks at what you type in and tries its best to give you a piece of data that makes sense. In your case.

```
yellow = False

color1 = bool(input('Enter your first primary color: \n'))

>>>yellow
```

the computer searches the program's namespace for the value of the expression yellow, which in this program is False.

It may help you to use raw_input(), which does not evaluate what is typed in and simply returns the string value of whatever is typed. For example:

```
input()
>>>yellow
```

would evaluate to False but

```
raw_input()
>>>yellow
```

would evaluate to the string value "yellow"

Try defining your color constants as strings rather than bools and processing input as a string as well. so

```
yellow = "yellow"
```

rather than

```
yellow = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use variables for the colors...I simply tested if the variable was=='color'

so my code was...

```
color1=input('Enter primary color:')
color2=input('Enter primary color:')


if color1=='red' and color2=='blue':
    print("When you mix red and blue, you get purple.")
elif color1=='red' and color2=='yellow':
    print("When you mix red and yellow, you get orange.")
elif color1=='blue' and color2=='red':
    print("When you mix blue and red, you get purple.")
elif color1=='blue' and color2=='yellow':
    print("When you mix blue and yellow, you get green.")
elif color1=='yellow' and color2=='red':
    print("When you mix yellow and red, you get orange.")
elif color1=='yellow' and color2=='blue':
    print("When you mix yellow and blue, you get green.")
else:
    print("You didn't input two primary colors.")
```